# How can one improve the performance of a query that selects on a low cardinality column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a "State" column that has a low cardinality (three possible value), on which most of my queries perform an equality selection (WHERE col = 'blah')  AFAIK you need something like a bitmap index to speed this up, which is not available in MySQL. The column value changes from state1 -> state2 -> state -> 3 etc., so I couldn't use partitioning.
How could one speed things up in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If there is something else in the `WHERE` clause, such as

```
WHERE state = 2 AND foo = "blah"
```

Then add a composite index

```
INDEX(state, foo)
```

Then the "cardinality" question applies to the combination of those two columns; the index is more likely to be used.

At the same time, drop the existing `INDEX(state)` as being useless; even 'in the way'.